# Проблема в history.js (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript, history-api, html5-history-api

Я не пойму как устранить следующую ошибку:

- заходим на сайт - [тыц](http://csgo-forecast.com)
- переходим на любой пункт меню
- жмем кнопку Back в браузере (я использую chrome)
- получаем ошибку:
- Элемент списка

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

Эта ошибка возникает в скрипте [main.js](http://csgo-forecast.com/js/main.js) на участке:

```
if(history.state.hasOwnProperty('url')!=null)
```

Как бы я не проверял url, ничего не выходит. Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильней было бы написать:

```
if(history.state && history.state.hasOwnProperty('url'))
```

hasOwnProperty - возвращает true или false.

Теперь по существу вопроса: когда история пуста, history.state == null. Браузер стирает и добаляет в историю последовательность переходов. Вы делаете один переход на другую страницу, в истории записан один переход, возвращаемся назад по кнопке Back, браузер удаляет этот переход и история снова пуста.

Comment: спасибо) разобрался